# Merging arrays to the one array from while loop

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I need an information to put from DB to arrays and then make one array.
So I wrote a following code:

```
     $sql0 = "SELECT * FROM ".$working_table." ORDER by id ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql0);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

     ${"emails_arr$row[id]"} = explode(",",$row['station_email']);

     echo print_r(${"emails_arr$row[id]"})."<br>";
 }

        $sql0 = "SELECT * FROM ".$working_table." ORDER by id ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql0);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $result_array = array_merge(${"emails_arr$row[id]"});

 }
        echo print_r($result_array);
```

the tricky part is that i don't know how to merge an arrays to one array from the while loop: `$result_array = array_merge(${"emails_arr$row[id]"});` 
it only shows the last array, other arrays are being rewrote.

Thank you guys!

Comment: `$result_array = array_merge($result_array, ${"emails_arr$row[id]"});` But you need to take care not to overwrite existing keys...

Comment: Try using this `$oldArray[]= $oldArray;`

Answer (score 0):

Change your while loop code with this one

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $result_array[] = array_merge(${"emails_arr$row[id]"});

 }
```

Notice the Square Brackets.

Comment: this one should work, but it makes a multi dimension array, I need just to merge all loopname generated arrays to one :)